# python idastar vs astar solving 8 puzzle

Tags: python, algorithm

I started to refresh my ai knowledge so i implemented some pathfind algorithms to solve 8-Puzzle.

- [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)
- [IDA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA%2a)
- [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)
- [IDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)

I was wondering why my implementation of IDA* has a longer path. It should be optimal like A*.

```
% python puzzle8.py -a idastar -d hard
IDASTAR - RESULT in 161.6099:
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | N

cost: 0 total_cost: 121
...
nodes 28

% python puzzle8.py -a astar -d hard
Max nodes 665 loops 1085
ASTAR - RESULT in 0.3148:
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | N

cost: 0 total_cost: 115
...
nodes 24
```

Code is on gist https://gist.github.com/1629405

***Update:***

Code is now pointing to a **working** version.

```
% python puzzle8.py -a idastar -d hard
IDASTAR - RESULT in 234.4490: 

1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | N
...
nodes 24
```

But i'm still wondering why IDA* takes so much longer under **python** than A*.

***Update 2:***

Code is changed prints now visited nodes.

IDASTAR creates **4184368** ASTAR **1748** nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your implementation of IDASTAR increments the limit by 10 with each iteration, which only guarantees that your solution will be no more than 9 more than optimal.  Change the increment to 1, and you should get an optimal result (but take longer to do so).

Comment: Thanks i changed my code to increments the limit now by 1. But a other question  why it tooks so damn **long** to finish in idastar?

Comment: How many iterations does idastar go through?  How many nodes does it expand in total, not just in the last iteration?  Answer those questions, and you should have the answer to yours.

Comment: Oh yeah right. Changed code maxnode counts now every viewed node. **ASTAR** has 1748 nodes and **IDASTAR** 4184368 nodes.

Comment: You could get the better (if not best) of both by STARTING by increasing the limit by 10 each iteration, and then doing a binary search for the correct limit, taking the midpoint between the last one that DIDN'T work an the last one that DID.